# Custom Dropdown and Combo Box problem?

Tags: html, css

I have a form.In that iam having my customized data dropdown.In one case combo box is below the custom data dropdown.when i click the dropdown th div iam caling has to come top of the combo box.It is not coming on the top the stack.the combo box and div are overlapping.
Any Suggestions to solve these problem?

Thanks 
Avinash

Comment: add some html and css code, so we can see what's going on.

Comment: Could you please provide your code here? I don't really understand how your code is. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is because controls like select boxes, iframes will be on top of other controls like div, span etc.

You can either hide the select box when the custom control is on top of it. This won't be a great idea.

Otherwise you can use another iframe to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is an IE-specific problem (fixed for IE8 I believe). The select element will always appear on top of anything else.

One solution is to create an iframe and position that underneath your dropdown. They are one of the few elements that will appear on top of the select element. http://www.clientcide.com/wiki/cnet-libraries/02-browser/02-iframeshim might be helpful.